# It is possible to start an embedded instance of apache Spark node?

Tags: java, mapreduce, apache-spark

I want to start an instance of a standalone Apache Spark cluster embedded into my java app. I tried to find some documentation at their website but not look yet.

Is this possible?

Comment: Stark industries FTW! Using Ironman clustering?

Comment: xD sorry mispell. Apache Spark

Comment: Just keep in mind that Spark will do things like add servlet endpoints for its own UI and potentially Prometheus metrics, which might be problematic or unwanted in the context of your app. You may wish to disable those, for example by setting `spark.ui.enabled` to `false`.

Answer (score 19):

You can create SparkContext in local mode, you just need to provide "local" as a spark master url to SparkConf

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().
  setMaster("local[2]").
  setAppName("MySparkApp")

val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes -- you can use Spark in an embedded way with a "local" master.

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();//Create new spark config
sparkConf.setMaster("local[8]"); // local, using 8 cores (you can vary the number)
sparkConf.setAppName("MyApp");
SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf);
```

This will run Spark within your JVM.

Comment: Can Spark run in a multithreaded setting? I want to embed Spark in Jboss, but it seems that Spark can run only once in a JVM.

Answer (score 4):

Others answered this question but as for 2020 with Apache Spark version 3.0:

Java example:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Your app name").master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
```

master("local[*]") means run in a standalone mode with all available CPU cores.

Maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```